# Removing a slot on a child button click

Tags: ruby, shoes

I've been trying to remove a slot from a child button click, but I can't seem to get it to work.  E.G.

```
flow do
  button("X") {parent.remove}
end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoes' blocks are sometimes [tricky](http://help.shoooes.net/Rules.html).  The key here is to ask yourself, what is the parent method being called upon?  `self`, of course.  And self references the app (or window, or dialog), not the button.

There are two similar ways to get around this.  First, you can create a reference to the button to use in the block:

```
flow do
  a = button("X") {a.parent.remove}
end
```

Or, you could just reference the slot itself:

```
b = flow do
  button("X") {b.remove}
end
```

Comment: Thanks I was trying something more complicated than I needed.  Now I can't figure out a method to call to force an update to the window.

Comment: Never mind, if I hide it then remove it the slot is updated properly.